# How can you fix an error 1958 when using SET PRINTER TO on Vista 64bit in VFP 8

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Our VFP 8 application is returning error 1958, which is "Error loading printer driver" when executing the following line of code

```
SET PRINTER TO HP1200
```

on a customers Vista Business 64bit laptop.  The HP1200 is a HP business ink jet model 1200.

The customer removed and reinstalled the printer using the latest 64bit driver from HP.  We've also tried added a new Generic / Text Only printer on the FILE: port and using it instead, and we get the same error.  So it's not specific to the HP printer driver.

We've also tried removing the `SET PRINTER TO` line and just executing the a `REPORT FORM` command so it will go to the default printer, but we get no output.

The customer has a desktop machine, 64 Vista Business as well, with the same printer and driver installed, and we do not see the same error.  They do run Avast antivirus on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have at least one client who is using Vista with a FoxPro application, but we are using FoxPro 9, and have had no printing problems.

From everything I have read, if you are going to use Vista and FoxPro together, FoxPro 9 is the way to go.

http://www.promatrix.com/mall/vfp-vista-compatibility.asp

We switched our app from Foxpro 8 to Foxpro 9, specifically for Vista compatibility... and although I was not directly involved, I don't think the change-over was hard to do.